# Which scholars say that the fast automatically is broken on sunset (maghreb)?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, sawm, islamic-scholar

Reading this [hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/63):

> ... قَالَ ‏"‏ إِذَا رَأَيْتُمُ اللَّيْلَ أَقْبَلَ مِنْ هَا هُنَا **فَقَدْ أَفْطَرَ الصَّائِمُ** ‏"‏‏

It seems one could understand the hadith in two different ways; (1) as it is interpreted and translated in sunnah.com:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) then said, "When you see night falling from this side, *the fasting person should break his fast*,"

or (2):

> The Prophet (ﷺ) then said, "When you see night falling from this side, *the fasting person has (automatically) broken his fast*,"

I am aware that the first interpretation is the most common.

In [Sharh Sahih Bukhari](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=3575&idto=3578&bk_no=52&ID=1238), Ibn Hajr Al-Asqalani mentions the following about that phrase:

> قوله : ( فقد أفطر الصائم ) أي : دخل في وقت الفطر
>
> It means: The time of breaking the fast has arrived.

Then he continues:

> ويحتمل أن يكون معناه : فقد صار مفطرا في الحكم لكون الليل ليس طرفا للصيام الشرعي
>
> It is possible that the meaning of it is: The fast has been broken because night is not a part of fasting in sharia...
>   *(edit an translate better if you wish)*

While doing this, he then explains that the first interpretation is the most valid.

## Which scholars say that the fast automatically is broken on sunset (maghreb)?

---

*Some might say; how can the fast be broken without eating or drinking? That is not so relevant to the direct question itself, but a fast answer would be the same way the fast automatically is broken for a woman who starts menstruating, same way it is broken for a man that for instances leaves islam or have sexual intercourse.*

---

It seems some hanafi fiqh books contains an inclination of that:

> { إذا أقبل الليل من هنا فقد أفطر الصائم } أي إذا وجدت الظلمة حسا في جهة المشرق فقد ظهر وقت الفطر أو صار مفطرا في الحكم ; لأن الليل ظرفا للصوم
>
> [رد المحتار على الدر المختار](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=1558&idto=1685&bk_no=27&ID=94#docu)
>
> ---
>
> { : إذا أقبل الليل من ههنا وأدبر النهار من ههنا فقد أفطر الصائم أكل ، أو لم يأكل }
>
> [بدائع الصنائع في ترتيب الشرائع](http://library.islamweb.net/Newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=12&ID=767)